# ASP.Net Identity Change Password account lockout does not work

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, penetration-testing

I am using ASP.Net identity.  In the changepasswordasync function an invalid old password does not trigger an account lockout, is there anyway to get this to happen?  This was raised as low issue by Pen test.

Regards

Mike

Comment: Hi Mike, have you set 'UserLockoutEnabledByDefault' value to true in ApplicationUserManager.cs file?

Comment: and the MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout needs to be considered

Comment: I should mention user lockout works fine for login. Does this mean I have got the above set?

Comment: Just checked and yes UserLockoutEnabledByDefault is set to true.  MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout is also being set to a number

Comment: you can lockout the user by following code if old password is incorrect
`user.LockoutEnabled = true;
user.LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60);
await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by calling lockout function if user provides wrong old password

```
int userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(userId , model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    userManager.ResetAccessFailedCount(userId);
}
else
{
    //you can add logic if the call didn't succeeded because of incorrect old 
    password and then execute the following line
    userManager.AccessFailed(userId);
}
```